# Parameterized MySQL query doesn't return any results

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I'm querying a MySQL Database from C# with .NET Connector 6.8.6

I've written the following Query function:

```
public DataSet ExecuteQuery()
    {
        try
        {
            this.dataset = new DataSet();
            dataset.Clear();

            conn = new MySqlConnection(this.queryConfig.GetConString());
            conn.Open();

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(this.queryText, conn);

            MySqlDataAdapter _mySQLAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            _mySQLAdapter.Fill(dataset);
            conn.Close();

            return this.dataset;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return this.dataset;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn != null) conn.Close();
        }

    }
```

Now I'm working on securing my Queries against SQL Injections.

This is my Query Function:

```
string queryText2 = string.Format("SELECT TABLE_NAME AS 'table_name', "
                             + "round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) AS 'Size(MB)'"
                             + "FROM information_schema.TABLES "
                             + "WHERE table_schema = @dbname");


            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(queryText2);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbname", Convert.ToString(databaseName));
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. @dbname in the query String never gets replaced by .Parameters.AddWithValue, and thus, the Query fails.

Is there any way I can get this to work without scrapping my complete Query class?

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: @Takarii No.  "@dbname" just doesn't get replaced with databaseName.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thats exactly what he is asking for help with....

Comment: The title has nothing to do with the question. *How* do you know the parameter isn't passed? Parameters are *not* substitution values, they are passed as part of the RPC call to the server. If you don't get the expected results, it's because there is no matching data

Comment: Moreover, what's the point of using String.Format when you simply return the same string?

Comment: @PanagiotsKanavos: This is definitely not the case. There is matching data on the server, and the query returns the expected result when I don't parameterize it but pass the input variable directly.

Comment: it seems like a daft question, but is a value actually being passed to the query? Your c# code doenst show any `databaseName` variable, and the sql string used is `queryText` (your second block shows the query string as `queryText2`

Comment: Another thing to check, is the parameter syntax for MySQL. Named parameters with a `@` prefix are used in SQL Server. MySQL may use a different format and simply not recognize them. Finally, what is `databaseName`? If it's a string, why try to convert it to string again?

Comment: @Takarii. Yes it is.

Comment: @Fang then either MySQL uses a different syntax or you aren't passing the value you think you are.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: Neither of that. However, I found a solution, even though I feel it is very crude. It works when I pass a MySQL Command object to the Query function. It seems to me that there's some internal MySQL stuff going on.

Comment: What Query function? There's no Query function in the question. I'll have to ask what Talarii asked - are you running the code you posted or something else? Were you setting the the text to the *wrong command object*?

Comment: @Panagitos Kanavos: I've posted the Query function in the first paragraph in the original question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93495/discussion-between-fang-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: You haven't posted anything like that. You have some text that mentions it, you don't provide the full code or show where it si called. From your comments it looks like you set the query text to the wrong field

Comment: I have to agree with @PanagiotisKanavos - Something is missing here. Your c# code block isnt calling your sql string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
public DataSet ExecuteQuery()
{
    ...
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(this.queryText, conn);
        // parameters are lost!!
        MySqlDataAdapter _mySQLAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

     ...
}
```

You are creating a *new* `MySqlCommand` by copying the command text but **you are *not* copying the parameters**.  Therefore the parameter you add gets lost.  I'd suggest reviewing your design to either stop copying sql from one command to another or to copy the parameters as well.

Answer (score -2):

Why not like this?

```
string queryText2 = string.Format("SELECT TABLE_NAME AS 'table_name', "
                                 + "round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) AS 'Size(MB)'"
                                 + "FROM information_schema.TABLES "
                                 + "WHERE table_schema = {0}",Convert.ToString(databaseName));
```

Comment: This isn't helpful. databaseName is already a String. String.Format in this case is redundant. Moreover, your "solution" doesn't help against possible SQL-Injections, which is the whole point of my question

Comment: **That** is a case of SQL injection. Besides, it will fail with a syntax error as there are no quotes around the value. The problem isn't with MySQL or using parameterized queries but the content of the parameter